# select Parent Child Rows in same Table

Tags: sql

I have table structure like below

```
id |parent|value
1  | 0    | a |
2  | 1    | b |
3  | 4    | c |
4  | 0    | d |
5  | 0    | e |
```

I want to display only rows that have a relation parent child

like:

```
id |parent|value
1  | 0    | a |
2  | 1    | b |
3  | 4    | c |
4  | 0    | d |
```

- every child should have a parent
- every parent should have at least one child

This is my code but it does not work properly:

```
select a.id, a.parent,a.value
from myTable a inner join myTable b 
on a.id = b.parent
union 
select b.id, b.child,b.value
from myTable a inner join myTable b
on a.id = b.parent;
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Can you post some examples with what you have tried?

Comment: see the above example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
     parent != 0
  OR EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM yourTable children
              WHERE chilren.parent = yourTable.id
            )
```

The first condition checks if the row points to a parent, and the second condition checks if the row has any children.

Comment: What if the table has undefined levels? Is there a way to do some kind of recursion?. Thanks!

Comment: @jrichardsz You should open a new question and refer to this answer if you feel it relevant.